# Spring MVC: How to deny access to any page that doesn't explicitly have a role assigned

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to ensure all resources have security permissions set, even if that's declaring the resource public (ROLE_ANONYMOUS).

How can I configure Spring MVC to deny any page that has no permissions assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting a rule at the end of your file mapping /** to the highest possible role in your scheme?